# Dash table updated in callback won't display

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I'm building a Dash app. I have a table of search results, and rows are selectable. I want to have a second table with only the rows selected in first table. So, the data for the 2nd table are updated in a callback function.

Here are the code samples:

**Layout:**

```
html.Div([
        html.Div(id='selection-table'),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='result-table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "selectable": True} for i in df_results.columns],
            data=df_results.to_dict('records'),
            row_selectable="multi",
            selected_rows=[],
            style_as_list_view=True,
            style_data={
                'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                'height': 'auto'
            },
            style_cell_conditional=[
                {'if': {'column_id': 'id'},
                'width': '5%'},
                {'if': {'column_id': 'targetsCount'},
                'width': '10%'},
            ]
        )
    ], 
    className='results'
    )
```

**Callback:**

```
@dash_app.callback(Output('selection-table', 'children'),
                    [Input('result-table', 'data'),
                    Input('result-table', 'selected_row_ids')])
def display_result_selection(data, selected_row_ids):
    if selected_row_ids is None:
        selected_row_ids = []
    df = pd.DataFrame() if data is None else pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df[df['id'].isin(selected_row_ids)]
    print(df)
    return [
            html.P('Current selection'),
            html.P(' '.join(df['id'].tolist())),
            dash_table.DataTable(
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True} for i in df.columns],
                data=df.to_dict(),
                row_deletable=True,
                style_as_list_view=True,
                style_data={
                    'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                    'height': 'auto'
                }
            )
        ]
```

*Expected result*: when I select a row in result-table, I want to have a new row in table inside selection-table

*Real result*:

- html.P components are correctly updated when I select rows,
- df is correctly updated (print),
- but table is never displayed!

I'm using Python 3.8.3 and Dash 1.16.3.

Any idea of what I missing here?
Thanks a lot

Comment: try with  `data=df.to_dict('records')` in the return of the callbalck, else the dict is not in the good structure for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frayal mentioned in comments, `data=df.to_dict('records')` did the trick, so that the dictionnary is in the good structure.